# Software for tracking how much time cows spend with each other, and who they interact with

Tags: database, camera, table

I am looking for a software recognition camera software for mountain cows, that can see at night as well. This software would track each cow, looking at how much time each cow spends with another cow, and report everything in a table. It should also report how much time each cow spends looking, one cow at another cow, and any potential aggressions of one cow towards another. Ideally, the software would be available online, so many people can observe, and, read the data (since they cannot observe 24 hours).

It would be nice if someone developed such a software system, or if it were available, also so people could track and view results over the web.

Thanks.

Comment: The cows can see at night, or you want recognition software that also works with night-vision cow-tracking cameras?

Comment: For how many weeks/months/years does the observation need to take place?  If you have a good horse and provide healthy food, I'll bring my saddle and night-vision goggles.

Comment: How many cows are we talking about and how large is the area? Because for detecting something like "cow A is looking at cow B" you need 3D cameras or effectively 2 cameras at every camera point and as mountain areas are typically very wide you need may be 20-30 camera positions which makes in total 40-60 cameras. Depending on the number of cows it might be easier to equip every cow with a GPS and a compass for detecting the view angle.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is this required for a farm or just for fun? I have come across solutions based on tagging cows with GPS but no camera... May be some vetinary equipment to monitor pulse, heartbeat etc, coupled with GPS location can detect aggression...